# In array,How I can make recognition between elements that are they IP?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ip

I have one array like bellow :

```
array = [["127.0.0.1"],["127.0.0.1"],[],[]]
```

and want to extract one of the IPs , The problem is I want to recognize the difference between one element that has IP and empty elements,first I make a filter for recognize number but can't get the result now I trying this way :

```
let IpString = array.split("\"");

///and gave me this bellow result

Array(5) ["[[", "127.0.0.1", "],[", "127.0.0.1", "],[],[]]"]
browser_prototype.js:268
length:5
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:"[["
1:"127.0.0.1"
2:"],["
3:"127.0.0.1"
4:"],[],[]]"
```

But I think I should find a way that can recognize between empty elements and IP elements then I need just one of the IP because always there are same and equal.
I looking for this bellow result :

```
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: `array.filter(arr => arr.length).map(arr => arr[0])` will give you `["127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"]`

Comment: If my array like in above Array(5) ["[[", "127.0.0.1", "],[", "127.0.0.1", "],[],[]]"] ,I can't do this code that you recommended @blex

Comment: The array you mention here is a result of the `split` you tried. My example was referring to the very first thing you said in your question _"I have one array like below"_. What come after that seems really dirty. If no one here gave an answer that helps you, please clarify your question, with what you actually have as an input, and what you want as an output. It will be easier to undestand

Comment: No I wrote what I need exactly just asked you if like that, but forget it,I have what I need , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get what your are trying to do, but you if you are sure your array will either be empty or have an IP in it, you might just have to check the length to see if there is anything in the array.

Here I'm using the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. It takes a callback with an argument and expect the callback to return a `boolean`

```js
const array = [["127.0.0.1"],["127.0.0.1"],[],[]];
// we use the filter function to check for the length of each sub-arrays.
// here, a length of 0 would evaluate as falsy, thus not including the empty array.
const ips = array.filter(item => item.length);
console.log(ips.length);
```

Optionally, thanks to [blex's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60849224/in-array-how-i-can-make-recognition-between-elements-that-are-they-ip/60849313#comment107657610_60849224), you might want to map your multi-dimensionnal array to a single dimension. It's easier for comprehension. If so, check our [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60849224/in-array-how-i-can-make-recognition-between-elements-that-are-they-ip/60849313#comment107657610_60849224)